# Given a DayOfTheWeek how do i get the date from an existing datetime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery calender that a user selects a date from.
I also have a list from Mon - Sun that the user can click on that would be the Monday through Sunday for the selected week from the calendar.

I can get the current day of the week using c#'s DayOfWeek method from jquery's selected date.
I have the user selected day of the week from the mon-sun list (1-7)

but how do i form a new date based of what day the user clicks on from the mon - sun list?

an example would be user selects Friday the 16th of Jan 2015 from Jquery Calendar.

They then click on the Monday from the Select list.

I should be able to calculate the Monday is the 12th of Jan 2015

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's you go,

```
        DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now; //your selected date

        DayOfWeek s = selectedDate.DayOfWeek; // your selected day of the selecteddate.
        DayOfWeek selectedWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday; //your selected weekday.

        DateTime output = selectedDate.AddDays((int)selectedWeek - (int)s); //output.
```

Comment: Actually just looking a bit closer, As Sunday is 0 in C#'s DayOfWeek enum i get out of range exception when  `selectedDate.AddDays((int)selectedWeek - (int)s);` is called. would you have any ideas as to work around this?

Comment: At which point of line you are getting the exception? Please input the data and where are you getting the exception. Since AddDays throws exception when resulting Datetime is less than **DateTime.MinValue** or greater than **DateTime.MaxValue**.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

and with

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 12);
```

you can get the DayOfWeek from a specific Day.

DayOfWeek is an enum. So when you have Monday it may have e.g. integer 1 behind. When you have Friday now you have e.g. integer 5 behind.

I think now you can calculate that Friday is 4 days later than Monday. so it is the DateTime(2015, 1, 12 + 4) for the Friday

Does this help?